# The EPS version of the Stack Exchange logo isn't available (404)

Tags: bug, status-completed, 404-not-found, logo

I'm trying to download the EPS version of the Stack Exchange logo from here: https://stackexchange.com/about/logos but I get a 404 page. Same goes for the other EPS logos.

Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should now be fixed, it was broken when we migrated build systems and didn't account for the `.eps` files used only here.